# Authentic Standard Life campaign?

Tags: product-placement, threads

One of the many haunting images from the nuclear post-apocalyptic film *Threads* is folk shuffling around a poster for *Standard Life* (a genuine, famous, UK insurance company) with the slogan "Standard Life for all of your life", as a critique of unrealistic expectations of security during the Cold War. Many people of my generation remember the image, and it is frequently used in stills.

While it's a minor issue in the broader context of the film, I'm a little curious as to:

- whether this was a genuine campaign of *Standard Life* at the time
- whether *Standard Life* approved its use
- whether they were publicly unhappy about its use

All possible answers to these questions seem implausible in the modern context, but it is quite an old film. Does anyone know, or know the industry at that time well enough to give even a likely answer?

[image: Standard Life for all of your life]

Comment: Partial answer: It was probably a real campaign since it's [the kid from the commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vG75iacqGnA).

Comment: Oh great, thanks @Walt . I'd failed even to find out whether it was a real campaign.

Comment: @Walt - Doesn't that answer the question then? I guess it doesn't answer whether or not they approved it, though.